# Spectral Measures: Constructions

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

*Any constructions welcome!!!*

Given a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$.

Regard spectral measures:
$$E:\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{C})\to\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})$$

That are additive:
$$E\left(\biguplus_kA_k\right)=\sum_kE(A_k)$$

And projection valued:
$$E(A)^2=E(A)=E(A)^*$$

As well as complete:
$$E(\mathbb{C})=1\quad E(\varnothing)=0$$

How to construct them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Construction**

Given a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$.

Regard an ONB $\mathcal{S}$.

Construct spectral measure:*
$$E(A)\varphi:=\sum_{\sigma\in\mathcal{S}}1_A(\lambda_\sigma)\langle\sigma,\varphi\rangle\sigma$$

Denote orthonormals:
$$\mathcal{S}_A:=\{\sigma\in\mathcal{S}:\lambda_\sigma\in A\}$$

Then it boils down to:
$$E(A)\varphi=\sum_{\sigma\in\mathcal{S}_A}\langle\sigma,\varphi\rangle\sigma$$

So they are additive:
$$E(A)+E(A')=E(A\uplus A')$$

And projection valued:
$$E(A)^2=E(A)=E(A)^*$$

As well as complete:
$$E(\mathbb{C})=1\quad E(\varnothing)=0$$

Regard disjoint Borel sets:
$$A_k\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{C}):\quad A_k\cap A_{k'}=\varnothing$$

Denote for readability:
$$A:=\biguplus_{k=1}^\infty A_k\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{C})$$

For an element find:
$$\varphi\in\mathcal{H}:\quad\#\mathcal{S}_\varphi<\infty\quad(\mathcal{S}_\varphi\subseteq\mathcal{S})$$

Such that one has:
$$\sum_{\sigma\in\mathcal{S}_\varphi^\complement}|\langle\sigma,\varphi\rangle|^2=\|\sum_{\sigma\in\mathcal{S}_\varphi^\complement}\langle\sigma,\varphi\rangle\sigma\|^2<\varepsilon$$

Choose the scalars:
$$\Lambda_\varphi:=\{\lambda_\sigma:\sigma\in\mathcal{S}_\varphi\}:\quad\#\Lambda_\varphi<\infty$$

Then one can find:
$$A_\varphi\cap\Lambda_\varphi:=(A_1\cup\ldots\cup A_K)\cap\Lambda_\varphi\supseteq A\cap\Lambda_\varphi$$

So one finally obtains:
$$\|E(A)\varphi-E(A_\varphi)\varphi\|^2\leq2\|\sum_{\sigma\in\mathcal{S}_A\cap\mathcal{S}_\varphi^\complement}\langle\sigma,\varphi\rangle\sigma\|^2+2\|\sum_{\sigma\in\mathcal{S}_{A_\varphi}\cap\mathcal{S}_\varphi^\complement}\langle\sigma,\varphi\rangle\sigma\|^2\\
=2\sum_{\sigma\in\mathcal{S}_A\cap\mathcal{S}_\varphi^\complement}|\langle\sigma,\varphi\rangle|^2+2\sum_{\sigma\in\mathcal{S}_{A_\varphi}\cap\mathcal{S}_\varphi^\complement}|\langle\sigma,\varphi\rangle|^2\leq4\sum_{\sigma\in\mathcal{S}_\varphi^\complement}|\langle\sigma,\varphi\rangle|^2<4\varepsilon$$

Concluding the spectral measure.

**Scalars may repeat: $\lambda_\sigma=\lambda_{\sigma'}$*

**Representation**

Given the Hilbert space $\ell^2(\mathbb{C})$.

Regard the ONB $\{\delta_\lambda\}_{\lambda\in\mathbb{C}}$.

Spectral measure becomes:
$$[E(A)\varphi](\xi)=\sum_{\lambda\in\mathbb{C}}1_A(\lambda)\langle\delta_\lambda,\varphi\rangle\delta_\lambda(\xi)\\
=\sum_{\lambda\in\mathbb{C}}1_A(\lambda)\varphi(\lambda)\delta_\lambda(\xi)=1_A(\xi)\varphi(\xi)=[1_A\varphi](\xi)$$

*(That is the canonical one.)*