# Spectral Measures: Special Spectrum

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

**Problem**

Given a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$.

Denote eigenvalues by:
$$\sigma_0(N):=\{\lambda\in\mathbb{C}:\mathcal{N}(\lambda-N)\neq(0)\}$$

Then arbitrary sets admit:
$$\Lambda\subseteq\mathbb{C}:\quad\sigma_0(N)=\Lambda\quad\sigma(N)=\overline{\Lambda}$$

For some normal operator:
$$N:\mathcal{D}(N)\to\mathcal{H}:\quad N^*N=NN^*$$

How can I construct such?

**Application**

For an open domain:
$$\Lambda\subseteq\mathbb{C}:\quad\Lambda=\Lambda^\circ\implies E(\partial\Lambda)=0$$

So the implication fails:
$$\Delta=\overline{\Delta}:\quad E(\sigma\cap\Delta)=0\nRightarrow\sigma\cap\Delta=\varnothing$$

It remains valid though:
$$\Delta=\Delta^\circ:\quad E(\sigma\cap\Delta)=0\implies\sigma\cap\Delta=\varnothing$$

*(As check for singular spectrum.)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Construction**

Given the Hilbert space $\ell^2(\Lambda)$.

Construct spectral measure:
$$E(A)\varphi:=\sum_{\lambda\in\Lambda}\delta_{\lambda\in A}\langle\delta_\lambda,\varphi\rangle\delta_\lambda$$

And its normal operator:
$$N:=\int\lambda\mathrm{d}E(\lambda):\quad N^*N=NN^*$$

Then it has as desired:
$$\sigma_0(N)=\Lambda\quad\sigma(N)=\overline{\Lambda}$$

Concluding the construction.

**Reference**

This builts up on: [Constructions](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1326150/79762)